# Remove Odd Elements From List

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a short function to remove odd elements from a list of Integers, my code being:

```hs
removeOdds :: [Int] -> [Int]
removeOdds lst = [ x | x <- lst, x `mod` 2]
```

Compiler returns -

```
Type error in boolean qualifier
*** Term           : x `mod` 2
*** Type           : Int
*** Does not match : Bool
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need

```
x `mod` 2 == 0
```

The `mod` function returns an `Int`, which has to be converted to a `Bool` before it can be used in as a conditional.

An alternate solution would be

```
evens :: [Int] -> [Int]
evens xs = filter even xs
```

And after doing eta-reduction, you could even define it as

```
evens :: [Int] -> [Int]
evens = filter even
```

Although I would suggest using a less restrictive type signature to allow all `Integral` types, since `even` has the signature `Integral a => a -> Bool`:

```
evens :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
evens = filter even
```

Comment: Aaah yes that makes sense. Apologies, I know it's probably a very elementary question, but I've just started learning the language.

Comment: @DarioP Don't apologize for having to ask questions about basic things.  You're still learning a language that is quite different from most programming languages, so it has a relatively steep learning curve.  Just keep practicing and soon you'll be the one answering these questions instead of asking them =)